# JDeveloper Error : (CMD property not found in autorun.inf)

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

actually i was trying to install the program `jdev_suite_121200_win64.exe` which i already downloaded from oracle web site but when i was trying to install it after the first page of installation i got this error `CMD property not found in autorun.inf`.
i already tried run as administrator & running the program through the CMD.
searched in Google & oracle forum just gave me this link `https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2559818`.which i couldn't get anything useful from it .

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is do as follow (did it on Windows 8.1 x64):

1. Install **7Zip** (x64 in my case) on your PC;
2. Right click on "jdev_suite_121300_win64.exe", select 7Zip and extract on a folder of your preference;
3. On a elevated command prompt (in my case I used **Windows PowerShell** running as administrator), go to the folder "Disk1", that had to be inside the folder you just extracted "jdev_suite_121300_win64.exe";
4. Do the follow command (without double quotes): `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\(..your JDK.., in my case jdk1.8.0_20)\bin\java.exe  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk;oracle.jre`;

Enjoy ;-) !!

Comment: I searched a lot on web. Finally this solution worked for me. The difference between the other and this one is semi colon after oracle.jdf . Thanks for sharing

Comment: I have used the following command:                                                                                      D:\jdev_suite_121300_win64\Disk1>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin"\java.ex
e -jar install\modules\ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk;oracl
e.jre

Comment: Powershell did not work for me, oldie cmd shell did it for me: ...\Downloads\jdev_suite_121300_win64\Disk1>"c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin\java.exe" -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk;oracle.jre Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That link you posted has a more or less working answer. I had the same problem and found that at the same time as this question. I'll post the answer here, along with what I had to do to get it working.

The answer:

```
1. Extract "jdev_suite_121200_win64.exe" file into C:\jdev_suite_121200_win64
2. In cmd go to C:\jdev_suite_121200_win64\Disk1
3. Execute follow command:
   C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java.exe (..your JDK..)  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk,oracle.jre
```

This answer, for whatever reason, actually failed every time I tried to install using the Java 7 jdk java.exe, and was incredibly frustrating. However, once I ran it with my Java 6.0_38 jdk java.exe, everything ran fine. The installer will tell you that the check for Java failed because it needs Java 7, but just ignore it and it installs fine.

Basically, follow the instructions above, and use a Java 6 jdk java.exe. My command that ultimately worked looked like this:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java.exe -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar DISKCNT=1 JRE_COMPONENT=oracle.jdk,oracle.jre
```

Answer (score 1):

Luiz' response is correct.  I was going to post it, but he beat me to the punch! :)  There is a very vague description of what Luiz did floating around out there, but a few people were confused with extracting the .exe file.  It is a self extracting exe file, so you can right click and use some sort of extracting program (I used 7zip like Luiz).
Here are the instructions that I typed up:

1. Extract jdev_suite_121300_win64.exe to C:\jdev_suite (create the folder) by right clicking and using 7zip.
2. In CMD go to C:\jdev_suite\disk1
3. Execute this command:
        C:\jdev_suite\Disk1>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"\java.exe -jar instal
   l/modules/ora-launcher.jar diskcnt=1 jre_component=oracle.jdk,oracle.jre

Hope this helps!  Thanks, Luiz.  I tried to up your answer, but I am just a mere nOOb!

Comment: Unexpected token '\java.exe' in expression or statement.  error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

Unzip jdev_suite_121200_win32.exe to jdev_suite_121200_win32.

Run install.exe available in jdev_suite_121200_win32\Disk1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simpler than this a lot. You need to extract nothing. Simply the installer is not finding its path to the java.exe file in the \bin directory in the the jdk file. You just need to specify the path to that directory.
If you use windows 7 or 8 do the following:

1. Go to **Computer** icon and click it with your right button
2. On the top left side of your window click on **Advanced system settings**
3. Under the advanced tab click on **Environment Variables**
4. Click **new** to add a system variable and call it path
5. Specify the name to your bin directory(Paste in on variable value). Generally it has the format

C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx\bin

6. Click ok and re-execute your Jdevelopper installer again.